# Error semantical: find a letter in a string Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python and my homework is to find the semantical error, can somebody give me a hand?
I know that this code is ONLY working on THE FIRST letter of each expresion, when instead it has to look for an "a" in the whole expresion and Return TRUE.
The output gives me
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
and it has to be
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
How can I fix it? so it works right

`````
`def has_a(expresion):
    n = len(expresion)
    i = 0
    while i<n:
        if expresion[i] == 'a':
            return True
        else:
            return False
        i += 1

has_a('UNSAM 2020')
has_a('abracadabra')
has_a('La novela 1984 de George Orwell')````

OUTPUT:
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the else statement in while which causes you logical error where it returns false if the first letter is not 'a' . Instead of that you can return false outside the while loop so that it will return only if it checks every character in the string

```
def has_a(expresion):
    n = len(expresion)
    i = 0
    while i<n:
        if expresion[i] == 'a':
            return True
        i += 1
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Really helpful for me as a beginner